# JAXBException while trying to execute docx4j

Tags: java, intellij-idea, docx4j

I have a code to generate word files in Java with IntelliJ idea using docx4j library which it work great in java 8 but when I did migrate to java 9 or 10 I get

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

that I can't get rid off I tried adding Moxy to library, class path but still the same exception.
I looked in this similar problem but didn't work for me [docx4j JXABException](https://www.docx4java.org/forums/tomcat-f23/problems-with-tomcat-and-docx4j-t1806.html)

Comment: isn't that what moxy library is for ?

Comment: @JasonPlutext its still not working :/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j)

Comment: i did saw that but i didn't try it i thought that docx4j integrated moxy as a solution for this apparently i thought wrong now i ll try to resolve the jxab with others methode thank you

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/48136912/1031689

Comment: using java se so don't think that will work

Answer (score 0):

I expect there is more work to do, but https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/tree/Java9 works in Eclipse Oxygen.3a 4.7.3a with Open JDK 9, at least.

**UPDATE 6 May 2018**

Deleted the Java 9 branch, since you can use master following https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/commit/0def93434bc9a3efcbbf214247572dc5b9e96616

Fix is in https://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/docx4j-nightly-20180506.jar and will be in v3.3.8 on its release.

Answer (score 0):

i did add jxab library jars and its working fine now hope it will not crash [jxab jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j/48136912#48136912/%22jxab%20jars%22)